# Checking to make sure Entity attributes in Core Data are not the same when saved

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, nspredicate

I have an app that is using Core Data. I have the app being able to add a new Entity and fill out the "name" attribute of that Entity. What I'm not sure how to do is make sure that there are not 2 Entities created with the same "name" attribute. I have read this article ([Constraints in Core Data](http://blog.zachorr.com/post/129785280807/core-data-unique-constraints)) on unique constraints and it seems a tad above where I am. So I am trying to take the code at the top of the page and implement that. Here is what I have:

```
// check to see if the name is already saved
        // check to see if the name is already saved
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

        fetchRequest.resultType = .ManagedObjectIDResultType

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ ", name)

        let results = coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        if (results.name == personName.text) {
            //don't use it!
        } else {
            //create it!
        }
```

The part that I'm not sure about is the NSPredicate, I want to look over my fetch request for the "name" attribute found on each Person Entity.

Comment: It looks like all you have done is change the name of the entity - have you tried changing the predicate?

Comment: sorry posted old code.. this is what I have been trying to get working

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up using

```
// check to see if the name is already saved
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

        fetchRequest.resultType = .CountResultType
        // check the name attribute against the person name input
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ ", personName.text!)

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;


        do{
            let results = try coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSNumber]
            let count = results.first!.integerValue

            if (count == 0) {
                //use it!
                print("You can use that name") 
            }else{
               // don't use it!
               print("You already have that name in use")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```